Twilio webhook POST to app api endpoint (hosted on heroku) hits status 403
My app works great in development, coded my own text messaging route in sveltekit. In development I use nGrok over http and that works great.
once deployed to heroku the incoming POST webhook (from an sms I'm sending using google voice to my twilio 10-code number), hits a status=403.
I can't seem to figure out what's going on. I have a domain and automatic CORS certs setup on heroku, I get the same code with or without this.
I tried using postman and sent the same POST raw data as twilio sent (I know twilio uses xml form data, but didn't try that), and it worked and the data payload hit my api and the app parsed it. So something about the interaction between twilio and heroku?
Here is my server code for the incoming POST , located at my api endpoint.
export async function POST({ request }) {
console.log(' ~ api/incomingMessages/+server ~  Received a POST request from Twilio');

// Parse the incoming request from Twilio
const text = await request.text();
const params = new URLSearchParams(text);

// Extract relevant data from the parsed parameters
const from = params.get('From') || 'Unknown Sender';
const body = params.get('Body') || 'No message content';
const to = params.get('To') || 'Unknown Receiver';
const sid = params.get('SmsSid') || 'Unknown Message ID';

// Prepare the message data object
const messageData = {
    twilio_sid: sid,
    from,
    to,
    body,
    direction: 'inbound',
    status: 'received',
    sent_timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    user_id: 'place holder',
    price: '',
    unread_status: true
};

// Check if the message has content
if (messageData.body !== 'No message content') {
    console.log(
        ' ~ api/incomingmessages ~ messageData ~ checking for duplicates in supabase: ',
        messageData.body
    );

    // Check if the message already exists in the database
    const { data: existingMessages, error: checkError } = await supabase
        .from('sms_messages')
        .select('twilio_sid')
        .eq('twilio_sid', messageData.twilio_sid);

    if (checkError) {
        console.error('Error checking for existing message in database:', checkError);
    } else if (existingMessages && existingMessages.length > 0) {
        console.log(
            ' ~ api/incomingMessages ~ Message already exists in database:',
            messageData.twilio_sid
        );
    } else {
        // Insert the new message into the database
        const { data, error: insertError } = await supabase
            .from('sms_messages')
            .insert([messageData]);
        console.log(' ~ api/incomingMessages ~ Inserted message into database:', messageData.body);
        if (insertError) {
            console.error('Error inserting message into database:', insertError);
        }
    }
}

console.log(` ~ api/incomingMessages ~ Parsed message to: ${to} from: ${from}: ${body}`);
// Emit an event with the new message data
messageEventEmitter.emit('newMessage', { to, from, body, sid });

// Respond to Twilio's webhook to acknowledge receipt
const response = new Response('<Response></Response>', {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
    }
});

// Call the function to check and update message prices
checkAndUpdateMessagePrices();
return response;}

Heroku Logs
2024-06-30T14:41:44.185964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/incomingMessages" host=vi-174d63aab910.herokuapp.com request_id=723e081a-a7fe-4270-a02f-ae226bc3a5bd fwd="54.174.11.136" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=403 bytes=148 protocol=https
Twilio Error Logs
Error: 11200
HTTP status 403
Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden

Check if disabling csrf solves the problem.

You nailed it, it was the CSRF setting in my seveltekit app. I'll need to whitelist twilio.  Thank you!
